# Why is it recommended to make a unique SAS token for each event hub publisher, assuming permissions are the same for each publisher?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

At [Event Hubs authentication and security model overview](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/event-hubs/event-hubs-authentication-and-security-model-overview.md), when describing how to create SAS tokens for event hub publishers, it is mentioned that SAS tokens should include a URI that ends with the publisher name (client identifier), and that one token should be created for each publisher.  What is the advantage of making a token for each client, assuming the permissions granted are the same for each client (publishing to the event hub)?  Is there logging that can differentiate between clients, or some other audit trail or benefit this provides?

Comment: To revoke publishing permissions per client maybe?